# Is it faster to access array[i] or *(pointerOfArray+i)

Tags: c#, pointers

In C# is it faster to access

```
value =  array[i];
```

or

```
fixed(Type123* pointerOfArray = arrayOfType123)
value =  *(pointerOfArray+i)
```

Is there any difference between these operations?  Is there a way `unsafe` and `fixed` could improve its access ?

Comment: Why don't you write some benchmarks and find out for yourself?

Comment: Not that it's a bad question to know the answer to, but I feel like if you're worried about performance to that degree, C# might not be the best language for what you're doing.

Comment: Accessing the array will do bounds checking which I don't think would be done using the pointer, but I think this performance increase would be negligible unless you are doing mission critical code. I could be way off on this, though.

Comment: Without accepted answer but nonetheless - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374815/true-unsafe-code-performance

Comment: If you've identified array access as being an actual bottleneck by profiling, it should be a relatively simple task to set up a similar benchmark to compare the pointer alternative to see if it changes things.

Comment: @DavidCrowell: Because that's not the way it should be done. The OP's benchmark would only give them the results for a single test, using a single compiler, on a single architecture. SO should aim to provide better answers than that.

Comment: @Douglas: Stack Overflow isn't really the place to crowdsource benchmarks on various platforms.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I wasn't suggesting that. I meant that SO should aim to provide substantive answers, such as the underlying reasons why one operation might be faster than the other (e.g. array bounds checking).