# C# Need faster method to find the maximum double value from a sub array

Tags: c#

I need a faster method to find the maximum double value from a sub array.

This is how I do it now:

```
static double FindMax(double[] x, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int i = startIndex;
    double max = x[i++];
    double value;
    while(i <= endIndex)
    {
        value = x[i++];
        if (value > max) max = value;
    }
    return max;
}
```

But it is a bit slow. I need a faster method. Any tips?

Comment: If you're just looking for ideas, you can split the array into n groups, run this code in parallel on n threads, and take the max of those n maxes.

Comment: Can you sort the array or use a Binary Search Tree instead?

Comment: If you sort the array, you can take the last item in it

Comment: No, I can't sort the array. It must remain as is.

Comment: `doubles.AsParallel().Max();` is ~3 times faster on my multicore machine but considerably less efficient in resource usage.

Comment: the `.AsParallel()` version is 6 times slower on my machine.

Comment: Why is this slow? It's O(n) already!

Comment: Why is the method you have posted not fast enough?  How have you benchmarked it?  Are you sure that this is causing you a bottleneck in your code?  Maybe this belongs on Code Review.

Comment: Unrolling your loop will improve runtime.

Comment: I have a big array of sample values that I need to put into a Chart. If I use all data the chart gets too slow to pan around. So I have tested to downsample the sampledata. When doing that I must make the big data into smaller data. But I don't want to loose the min and max values from every chunk of data that is shrunk.  It all works, but gets slow when I zoom out.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The linked item is for actionscript and is comparing a native check against interrupted code.  Nothing like that would work here.

Comment: Do you really need the fidelity of all of the data when zoomed out?   While it wont be as accurate you could skip some of the elements with down sampling and caching.

Answer (score 9):

Raw `while` or `for` is likely the fastest version you can have in C# with single threaded code (the only thing you pay is boundary checks - `unsafe` may give you a bit more performance by avoiding bounds checks). Any LINQ on top of that would just slow things down.

Max is O(n) operation - if you need faster than that you need to use other data structures to store information. Sorted array would be the fastest (O(1) for max/min) but cost a lot to insert, heap or sort trees could be an option too.

Alternatively you can simply track max value of the array on all operations on it. You'll have to wrap array and pay a bit on every operation to keep "max" up to date all the time, but you'll get O(1) for max and keep all other operations on array at the same performance and preserve order.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at *unsafe* code. As far as I know, it lets you surpass bounds checking of built-in arrays, what would be faster.

**Edit:**
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374815/true-unsafe-code-performance) has some answers that might be interesting.

Comment: I will have a look at that. I'm used to pointers in C. But I have not tried them in C#. Must read how to use them.

Comment: See my edit. Also, to be able to use unsafe code in your VS project, you have to check "use unsafe code" in project properties.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code that performs faster (this is even faster than the unsafe/pointer code) ...

```
static double FindMaxFastest(double[] x, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int i = startIndex;
    double max = double.MinValue;
    do
    {
        if (max < x[i])
            max = x[i];
    } while (i++ < endIndex);
    return max;
}
```

You can try unsafe/pointer math in C# but it won't gain you the boost you expect. `unsafe` can also even decrease performance as the compiler and runtime can't do some of its internal optimizations.

```
static unsafe double FixMaxFixed(double[] doubles, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    var i = startIndex;
    double max = double.MinValue;
    fixed (double* p = doubles)
    {
        do
        {
            if (max < *(p + i))
                max = *(p + i);
        } while (i++ < endIndex);
    }
    return max;
}
```

... here is the test harness I used ...

```
static void Main()
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    var set = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).Select(i => rnd.NextDouble() * 100).ToArray();
    var s = 50;
    var e = 1000000;

    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    var r = new[] { new List<long>(), new List<long>(), new List<long>() };

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        FixMaxFixed(set, s, e);
        sw.Stop();
        r[0].Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);

        sw.Restart();
        FindMax(set, s, e);
        sw.Stop();
        r[1].Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);

        sw.Restart();
        FindMaxFastest(set, s, e);
        sw.Stop();
        r[2].Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
    }

    //5721.785 6098.866 5432.225
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", r.Select(i => i.Average())));
    Console.Read();
}
```

... Using a [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) can really increase the performance ([unrolling your loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)) ...

**(This runs in 50% of the time of my first example if the set is in descending order... 75% of the time if it is in ascending order)**

```
static double FindMaxDuff(double[] x, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    double max = x[startIndex];

    switch ((endIndex - startIndex) % 10)
    {
        case 0:
            if (max < x[startIndex++]) max = x[startIndex];
            goto case 9;
        case 9:
            if (max < x[startIndex++]) max = x[startIndex];
            goto case 8;
        case 8:
            if (max < x[startIndex++]) max = x[startIndex];
            goto case 7;
        case 7:
            if (max < x[startIndex++]) max = x[startIndex];
            goto case 6;
        case 6:
            if (max < x[startIndex++]) max = x[startIndex];
            goto case 5;
        case 5:
            if (max < x[startIndex++]) max = x[startIndex];
            goto case 4;
        case 4:
            if (max < x[startIndex++]) max = x[startIndex];
            goto case 3;
        case 3:
            if (max < x[startIndex++]) max = x[startIndex];
            goto case 2;
        case 2:
            if (max < x[startIndex++]) max = x[startIndex];
            goto case 1;
        case 1:
            if (max < x[startIndex++]) max = x[startIndex];
            break;
    }

    do
    {
        if (max < x[startIndex + 1]) max = x[startIndex + 1];
        if (max < x[startIndex + 2]) max = x[startIndex + 2];
        if (max < x[startIndex + 3]) max = x[startIndex + 3];
        if (max < x[startIndex + 4]) max = x[startIndex + 4];
        if (max < x[startIndex + 5]) max = x[startIndex + 5];
        if (max < x[startIndex + 6]) max = x[startIndex + 6];
        if (max < x[startIndex + 7]) max = x[startIndex + 7];
        if (max < x[startIndex + 8]) max = x[startIndex + 8];
        if (max < x[startIndex + 9]) max = x[startIndex + 9];
        if (max < x[startIndex + 10]) max = x[startIndex + 10];
    } while ((startIndex += 10) < endIndex);

    return max;
}
```

Comment: And I learned about Duff´s device :-)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice.

Comment: yeah, I could probably get it go a bit faster but I didn't feel like fighting the improvement as it would only improve the first 1 to 10 checks. You could also try a difference size Duff's device but it probably won't change the performance much at all.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the amount of element you have, there are some scenarios that your algorithm runs faster than others. For example, if you use the HeapSort, the order of sorting is O(n log n) and then pick in the maximum is O(1). Now you want the second max, you can mark the max with a boolean and again you can run the Heapsort for the same collection looking just the values that ar not marked. The order still the same. For references you can go here 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best computational complexity you'll get for an unsorted array is O(n).

You *could* maintain two copies of the array (one sorted, one unsorted) if you don't mind the extra complexity and memory consumption. (It would also incur some cost "up front" for creating the second array).

Otherwise, as others have indicated, you could parallelize this. That won't alter the computational complexity, but it could potentially improve the performance. Note the word "could" - parallelizing typically incurs some overhead too.